# Catch bundle identifier com.company.app in file name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, bundle-identifier

I am wondering how to catch bundle identifier like `com.company.appname` in file name `Great.app.ios9.1-com.company.appname.super-ultra.ipa` using `preg_match()` in php.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the dot separated words (*upto the third dot*) exists next to -.

```
$match = preg_match('~-\K(?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*~', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rR6aU3/1)

Comment: ok and it is possible to do it generaly, for example anywhere in file it can find it. Because for this it not working.  `SparKauf-v1.1.3-mac-iOS7.0-(Ultra-1.4.7).at.spar.sparkauf.plist`

Comment: ok, I rearranged my file names so identifier started with two dashes like `Keynote_Remote-1.2--com.apple.iwork.KeynoteRemote.ipa` but there is a problem, sometimes identifier consists of three parts `domain.company.app` sometimes of fourparts `domain.company.subapp.app` like example above. It is possible to do regex, which accepts this two parts?